# Running count distinct over a column - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, cumulative-sum

I want to aggregate the DAYS column based on the running distinct counts of `CLIENT_ID`, but the catch is `CLIENT_ID` that were seen from the previous DAYS should not be counted. How to do this in `Oracle` SQL?

Based on the table below (let's call this table `DAY_CLIENT`):

```
DAY CLIENT_ID

1   10
1   11
1   12 
2   10
2   11
3   10
3   11
3   12
3   13
4   10
```

I want to get (let's call this table `DAY_AGG`):

```
DAYS CNT_CLIENT_ID

1    3
2    3
3    4
4    4
```

So, in day 1 there are 3 distinct client IDs. 
In day 2, there are still 3 because `CLIENT_ID` 10 & 11 were already found in day 1. In day 3, distinct clients became 4 because `CLIENT_ID` 13 is not found on previous days.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution that may or may not be more performant than the other solutions:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 DAY, 10 CLIENT_ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 DAY, 11 CLIENT_ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 1 DAY, 12 CLIENT_ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 DAY, 10 CLIENT_ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 DAY, 11 CLIENT_ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 DAY, 10 CLIENT_ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 DAY, 11 CLIENT_ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 DAY, 12 CLIENT_ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 DAY, 13 CLIENT_ID FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4 DAY, 10 CLIENT_ID FROM dual)
SELECT DISTINCT DAY,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN client_id END) OVER (ORDER BY DAY) num_distinct_client_ids
FROM   (SELECT DAY,
               client_id,
               row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY DAY) rn
        FROM   your_table);

       DAY NUM_DISTINCT_CLIENT_IDS
---------- -----------------------
         1                       3
         2                       3
         3                       4
         4                       4
```

I recommend you test all the solutions against your data to see which one works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

One approach used a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d1.DAYS,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d2.CLIENT_ID) FROM yourTable d2
     WHERE d2.DAYS <= d1.DAYS) AS CNT_CLIENT_ID
FROM yourTable d1
```

Here is a demo below for SQL Server, but it should also run on your Oracle.  I always struggle with setting up Oracle demos.

### Demo

Comment: Awesome! I never thought it would be that simple thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `apply` operator if `oracle` support.

```
select day, CNT_CLIENT_ID  
from DAY_CLIENT t cross apply (
    select count(distinct CLIENT_ID) as CNT_CLIENT_ID
    from DAY_CLIENT
    where day <= t.day) tt 
group by day, CNT_CLIENT_ID;
```

In other way use `subquery` with `correlation` approach

```
select day, (select count(distinct CLIENT_ID) 
             from DAY_CLIENT
             where day <= t.day) as DAY_CLIENT
from DAY_CLIENT t
group by day;
```

Comment: This works too thanks! I haven't encountered the cross apply command before, glad that it worked.

Comment: FYI, I tried this with my dataset and the CROSS APPLY version took significantly longer  than the correlated subquery (I killed it after 2 minutes). The CBO suggested the same thing, that CROSS APPLY would take 10 times longer. The table's primary key includes both the "day" and "client_id" columns, though possibly in the wrong order to be useful here.

Answer (score -1):

Try to keep it simple, always. All other answers also good if you want to learn other ways. But in this case no need to be fancy at all.

```
SELECT days
     , COUNT(DISTINCT client_id) cnt
FROM
(
 SELECT 1 days, 10 client_id FROM dual --1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1, 11 FROM dual --2
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1, 12 FROM dual --3
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1, 11 FROM dual --4
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 10 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 11 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 12 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 10 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 11 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 12 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 13 FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4, 10 FROM dual
)
GROUP BY days
ORDER BY 1
/
DAYS | CLIENT_ID
----------------
 1          3
 2          3
 3          4
 4          1
```